# ROUNDUP current date to either 15th or end of the month

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am getting an "expected array" error on Today = Day(Today()). I have no idea what is wrong.

```
Dim Thisday As Integer
Dim Montho As Integer
Dim Yearo As Integer
Dim Lday As Integer
Dim last as Integer
last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Thisday = Day(date)
Montho = Month(date)
Yearo = Year(date)
Lday = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, -1))
```

Then Column B in excel gets populated with the same date, either the 15th or the last day.

```
If Thisday <= 15 Then
Range("B2:B" & Last).Value = Montho & "/15/" & Yearo
End If
If Thisday > 15 Then
Range("B2:B" & Last).Value = Montho & "/" & Lday & "/" & Yearo
End If
End Sub
```

Also not every month ends on the 30th, so how do get the Lday should return the as day of the month.

Comment: Still came up with the same error message.

Comment: sorry - my mistake: Scott has it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Date` instead of `Today`.

Do not use the same name as functions, excel gets messed up.

vba does not have `EoMonth` it is part of Application.WorksheetFunction.  It also returns a date or double not an integer.  You will need to get the `Day`:

```
Dim Today As Integer
Dim Montho As Integer
Dim Yearo As Integer
Dim Lday As Integer
Dim last As Integer
last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Today = Day(Date)
Montho = Month(Date)
Yearo = Year(Date)
Lday = Day(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0))


If Today <= 15 Then
    Range("B2:B" & Last).Value = Montho & "/15/" & Yearo
End If
If Today > 15 Then
    Range("B2:B" & Last).Value = Montho & "/" & Lday & "/" & Yearo
End If
```

---

The above code returns a string that looks like a date.  To return a true date use this:

```
Dim Today As Integer
Dim Montho As Integer
Dim Yearo As Integer
Dim last As Integer
last = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Today = Day(Date)
Montho = Month(Date)
Yearo = Year(Date)


Range("B2:B" & Last).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
If Today <= 15 Then
    Range("B2:B" & Last).Value = DateSerial(Yearo, Montho, 15)    
End If
If Today > 15 Then
    Range("B2:B" & 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(Date, 0)
End If
```

Comment: Still came up with the same error message, but thanks for correcting the parts.

Comment: Then the error is not with the code you are showing.  I get it to work without issue. @PhilippeMa  make sure you did not declare a variable `Date`

Comment: That is all my code and I do not have a variable set as Date. However, your 
    Date is showing up blue and mine are not.

Comment: It only shows blue here, not in my vbe.  If this is all where are you assigning a value to the variable `Last`?

Comment: Oh that was in a separate macro let me add that part.

Comment: I get no error with either code.  Is the error the same on the same line or different?

Comment: It says complie error: expected arrary. It highlights month on the line "Montho = Month(Date)".

Comment: Did you change the variable name to something but `Month` like I did.  I changed it to `Montho`

Comment: oh you guessed it. I didn't change all the variables to match. Thanks it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Range("B2:B" & Last).Value = dateserial(year(date), month(date)-(day(date)>15), 15 * abs(day(date)<=15))
```